# Не получается запустить jar file на сервере с php

Tags: php, java, jar

Здравствуйте. 
Возникла такая проблема. Надо запустить jar-файл на сервере при помощи php. Попробовал exec() и shell_exec().

Java файл внутри выглядит так:

```
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String name = args[0];
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
```

Код PHP выглядит следующим образом:

```
<?php

$arg1 = "some text";

exec("java -jar TEST.jar $arg1",$output);

echo $output[0]."<br/>";

echo $output[1];

echo "-------------------------------";

$shell_out = shell_exec("java -jar TEST.jar $arg1");

echo $shell_out;

?>
```

Но ни одно echo не срабатывает. И страница браузера остается пустой. Возможно ли, что это из-за того, что на сервере включен безопасный режим?

Comment: А если подключиться по SSH и попытаться выполнить эту команду в терминале?

Comment: Я не PHP разработчик, но вообще, что бы я сделал, чтобы понять в чём проблема: 1) Попытаться запустить jar этой же командой, подключившись по SSH. 2)Попытаться выполнить обычный `ls` из PHP. Если оба этих варианта сработают, то нужно думать дальше

Answer (score 1):

Может быть и прошло много лет, но отвечу, вдруг кому пригодится.
У меня заработало именно так:

```
$runJava = '"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251\bin\java.exe" -jar C:\Users\Admin\Documents\GetInfoFile\out\artifacts\GetInfoFile_jar\GetInfoFile.jar --folder "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\2020.02" 2>&1';
$output = shell_exec($runJava);
```